# Loop over a specific key in JSON using Jade

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug

I am working with node.js and using Jade as the template engine.
I have JSON response that I am getting from the API.

Fairly standard.
This is what it looks like:

```
Rows: 
{ Row: 
  [ { Header: 
       { ColData: 
          [ { value: 'GS & CO' },
            { value: '' },
            { value: '' },
            { value: '' },
            { value: '' },
            { value: '' },
            { value: '' } ] },
      Rows: 
       { Row: 
          [ { ColData: 
               [ { value: '01/31/2014' },
                 { value: 'Bill' },
                 { value: 'FY/2013-01/2014' },
                 { value: '01/31/2014' },
                 { value: '9963.14' },
                 { value: '9963.14' },
                 { value: '9963.14' } ],
              type: 'Data' },
            { ColData: 
               [ { value: '02/28/2014' },
                 { value: 'Bill' },
                 { value: '02/2014' },
                 { value: '02/28/2014' },
                 { value: '6378.14' },
                 { value: '6378.14' },
                 { value: '16341.28' } ],
              type: 'Data' },
            { ColData: 
               [ { value: '03/31/2014' },
                 { value: 'Bill' },
                 { value: '03/2014' },
                 { value: '03/31/2014' },
                 { value: '2556.0' },
                 { value: '2556.0' },
                 { value: '18897.28' } ],
              type: 'Data' },
            Summary: 
            { ColData: 
             [ { value: 'Total for GS & CO' },
               { value: '' },
               { value: '' },
               { value: '' },
               { value: '27567.44' },
               { value: '27567.44' },
               { value: '' } ] },
      type: 'Section' },
```

In my server (app.js), I pass the JSON to the view like so:

```
res.render('home.jade', {title: "hello",
                          reportname: report["Header"]['ReportName'],
                          daterange: "From:"+report["Header"]["StartPeriod"]+" to: "+report["Header"]["EndPeriod"],
                          alldata: report,
                          columns: report["Columns"],
                          rowsperclient: report["Rows"]["Row"]
                        });
```

In my view, I am trying to build a table using the columns and row data provided to me by the JSON. I am hitting a wall when I want to loop over just the `Header` parts of each `Row`.

```
  // First loop returns total number of records
  // for our API call
  each row, idx in rowsperclient
    each header, idx2 in row
      h5= idx2 +" -> "+rowsperclient[idx]
```

This gives me the following HTML output:

```
Header -> [object Object]

Rows -> [object Object]

Summary -> [object Object]
```

What I am trying to do is display the first value of each header - this is the company name.
Then I want to loop over the `ColData` and display it accordingly.

I can't figure out how to just loop over the `Header` portion in each row.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like

```
each cell, idx in rowsperclient.Header.ColData
    h5= idx +" -> "+ cell.value
```

Or like

```
each row in rowsperclient.Rows.Row
    each cell, idx in row.ColData
        h5= rowsperclient.Header.ColData[idx].value +" -> "+ cell.value
```

---

By the way, the structure has really bad names (rows in rows, "row" (variable name without plural) for collection, "rows" for not-a-collection, ...). That makes development and maintainability a lot harder.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try your solution. This JSON is from the Quickbooks API. It is a pain to read, that is true.

Comment: I did try both of the solutions. In both cases I get "Cannot read property ColData/Row of undefined" Does this have anything to do with the fact that my JSON is not stringified?